# Jenkins Workflow average full runtime - many years

Tags: jenkins-workflow

Anyone have an idea why my workflow job is showing "Average full run time: ~45y 358d"? I imagine it has something to do with a timestamp?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug in the CloudBees proprietary plugin `cloudbees-workflow-plugin`. Not fixed yet.